# Is there a way to group all of my Exception cases into a single class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, exception

I am building an API for post, get, etc a file and want to handle all possible exceptions that may occur. How can I go about grouping all exceptions into a single class which encapsulates all the cases which are being called repeatedly?

Ex:

```
except KeyError as e:
    log.info(e, exc_info=True)
    resp_dict = {'status': 'unsuccessful', 'message': 'Key error', 'data': ''}
    response = Response(response=json.dumps(resp_dict), status=400, mimetype='application/json',
                                headers=base_headers)
except FileExistsError as e:
    log.info(e, exc_info=True)
    resp_dict = {'status': 'unsuccessful', 'message': 'File already exists', 'data': ''}
    response = Response(response=json.dumps(resp_dict), status=400, mimetype='application/json',
                                headers=base_headers)
```

These are being called repeatedly in many places. How can I go forward in this case?

Comment: You can provide a tuple of exception classes to catch: `except (KeyError, FileExistsError)  as e:`. However, your handler still depends on the exact type, so I might just define a paramterized handler function to call from each block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group them in a tuple and use `e.__class__.__name__` to get the exception name/type:

```
except (KeyError, FileExistsError) as e:
    log.info(e, exc_info=True)
    resp_dict = {'status': 'unsuccessful', 'message': e.__class__.__name__, 'data': ''}
    response = Response(response=json.dumps(resp_dict), status=400, mimetype='application/json',
                            headers=base_headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can handle different exceptions all using a single block of code, they can be grouped together in a tuple as shown in the code given below :

```
try:
    ...
except FirstException:
     handle_first_one()

except SecondException:
    handle_second_one()

except (ThirdException, FourthException, FifthException) as e:
    handle_either_of_3rd_4th_or_5th()

except Exception:
   handle_all_other_exceptions()
```

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html